# Отправка писем php

Tags: php, mysql

Привет друзья! Есть вопрос, сделал отправку писем с помощью php. На денвере работает хорошо, письма приходят. Протестировал на хостинге jino сначала работало потом ошибка выходила. Примерно через 30 мин - 1 час письма снова нормально заработали и вот так постоянно. Отправлю несколько писем потом ошибка, пройдет время и опять работает. В чем проблема? Вот собственно сам код:

```
    $stext = "Текст";
                $subject    = "Тех поддержка";
                $headers    = "From: ".$adminmail."\n";
                $headers    .= "Reply-to: ".$adminmail."\n";
                $headers    .= "X-Sender: < http://".$cfgURL." >\n";
                $headers    .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows 1251\n";
                $send = mail($adminmail,$subject,$stext,$headers);

                if(!$send) {
                print "Ошибка почтового сервера! Приносим извинения за предоставленные неудобства";
            } else {
              print "Сообщение отправлено";
}
```

Может сделать отправку с smtp? Что посоветуете. Да и еще, почты $adminmail ставил и яндекс и gmail и даже хостинговый.

Answer (score 2):

Если почта уходит с перебоями, скорее всего проблема самого сервера. Лучше всего по данному вопросу обратиться в тех. поддержку Вашего хостера.

Comment: Написал, жду ответа. Значит это не в коде проблема? Может сделать с smtp?

Comment: В коде нет проблем, если Вам сам PHP об этом не сказал. Почему у вас почта как попало уходит, лучше чем Ваша тех поддержка никто не знает.

Comment: Спасибо) подожду ответа.

Comment: Сейчас вообще перестал отправлять. Что происходит не понимаю

Comment: Если $send вернуло true — то, точно к хостеру.

Comment: Я уже все по перезалил заново на хостинг, все перепроверил и ничего. Днем отправил примерно писем 30 для теста, после этого начал отправлять с перебоями. Сейчас у меня вечер и теперь вообще не отправляет. Днем хоть с перебоями отправлял

Comment: Может подскажите хороший хостинг?

Answer (score 1):

Лично я бы Вам посоветовал сделать через smtp. Сам раньше делал как Вы, но потом письма стали попадать в спам, либо вообще не приходить. Нашел замечательную библиотеку: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
Подключается очень просто. Попробуйте, не пожалеете... Если что, спрашивайте...

Comment: Спасибо большое) я в php не спец и только по примерам могу что то понять) ладно почитаю. Кстати всем спасибо, отписал в службу поддержки хостинга и действительно отправка из за сбоя не происходила. Сейчас исправили и письма приходят буквально через секунду. Конечно smtp лучше будет, попробую разобраться) Еще раз спасибо всем. Да кстати если кто хорошо понимает в php и ajax посмотрите мой пост http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422761/Авторизация-обработка-через-ajax